# How to activate and select a USB WiFi dongle in a Chromebook, instead of the built-in device?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, wifi-configuration, chromebook

Our school-provided HP Chromebook 11 G5 has problems handling video calls over WiFi. Doing some research, I found out that many generic WiFi USB dongles are available and are supposedly compatible with Chromebooks. So I ordered one and plugged it in the Chromebook's USB port.

However, I can't figure out how to select this adapter over the built in WiFi modem. When opening the system configuration pane, there is no such configuration in the Network/WiFi "tab", and no network group is listed in the Devices tab.

How can I select the USB WiFi adapter instead of the built in device?

---

**Update:**

I tested the dongle in my Windows laptop. It is working properly. Windows revealed that its chipset is Realtek RTL8818FTV.

I could not find drivers in the Realtek website, but I found these Windows drivers in another website:

https://oemdrivers.com/network-realtek-rtl8818eu-wireless-adaptor

Are there any 3rd party Chrome OS drivers for the Realtek chipset?

Comment: You need to look on the USB device for the software installer for Chromebooks. Before you do much, ask the seller to ensure there is a Chromebooks driver and return it if not.

Comment: I emailed the ebay seller. I am skeptical that I get an answer for a cheap generic adapter... But let's hope.

That aside, assuming there are Chrome OS drivers, and that I am able to install them (this is a school-provided machine so I am not sure it will allow this), then will the device show in the Devices tab?